# How do I deploy an app using the azure app service publish profile in VSCode?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

We have a web app hosted on Azure App Service. We've been given a publish profile for this app on Azure. If it was Visual Studio, I'd have done an import of this profile and would deploy the app. However in vscode, I don't see any options to import the publish profile. How can I now deploy the app with just the publish profile in hand? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code use Zip-Deploy while the publish profile has Web-Deploy and FTP credentials.  The easiest way for you would be to use an FTP client with the FTP credentials found in the publish profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`Azure App Service extension`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01?tabs=powershell) to deploy directly from VSCode which will acts similar to how you build profile in Visual studio